# Call a method in scrollViewDidScroll with low frequency

Tags: swift

I have a method that manage constraints, while some conditions are met. That method is placed inside `scrollViewDidScroll` methood:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    partiallyHideOverallViewOnScrolling(scrollView)
    scrollToNewRowsIfNeeded()
  }
```

Recently I discover freezes and weird behaviour while scrolling table, is there are possibility to call method inside `scrollViewDidScroll` no more then, for example, every 0.1 second?

It appears that method called 111 times on single drag down, when there is not much items in a `tableView`, that's quite a lot

Comment: Do you consider to use `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and `scrollViewWillEndDragging`  to know when the drag starts and ends.  Because every time scroll bounds changes,`scrollViewDidScroll` is called and that would not be necessary.

Comment: @DoganAltinbas I know about such methods but I need to smoothly move constraints while scroll is scrolling

Answer (score 0):

even though Dogan Altinbas's comment suggesting to use `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and `scrollViewWillEndDragging` sounds like the right approach to me I'd like to answer your question.

Just a quick example I created in a playground:

```
import UIKit

var date = Date()

while (true) {
    if Date().timeIntervalSince(date) > 1 {
        print("foo")
        date = Date()
    }
}
```

You'll see it'll only print once per second. I just remember the last time I fired the event I wanted to fire and go from there.

Cheers,
Dominic